# Call the burn function of an ERC1155 token from another contract

Tags: solidity, erc-1155, burn

Quick question, I have 2 ERC1155 smart contracts

- Contract 1 is burnable
- Contract 2 has an interface to call the burn function

How do I assure the burning of let's say 10 tokens from contract 1 to be able to mint from contract 2 ?

A require or an if doesn't work because the burn function from contract 1 doesn't return a bool it's the standard open zeppelin ERC1155Burnable implementation

Thanks ahead

Comment: correct me if im wrong but if the burn function doesnt go through then it will create an error and the following code wont run regardless? if theyre seperate transactions then burn emits an event "TransferSingle" you should listen for that and only pass the second transaction if that event is emitted

Comment: Correct I didnt see the internal _burn which checks the balance thank you